# Casual error "can't create/write" err code 17

Tags: php, mysql, centos, tmp

from a month I purchased a VPS with Centos 6 and Plesk 11.0.

Since a few days (more often) happens that I get an email from cron plesk and all the sites with a mysql db fall with the error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_2a4_0.MYD' (Errcode: 17)
```

I checked and it's not a permission problem (mysql user is able to write without problems), I thought it was a problem of "numfiles" but since the problem persists even when it's below this limit and also manifests itself only ever temporary files to mysql, I tried to replace tmp folder with another, but problem it's still here (if possible even more frequently).

I do not know which way to turn...

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you try to google this, because google search engine contains many information regarding this error https://www.google.com/#q=Can't+create%2Fwrite+to+file+(Errcode%3A+17) This link too http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/1-cant-create-write-file-tmp-sql_17bf_0-myd-errcode-17-a-208382.html

Comment: Yes, i did it. Nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try command:

```
chmod 1777 /tmp
```

or check if you have run out of disk space in the partition:

```
df -h
```